# Is the manga Kingdom based on historical events?

Tags: kingdom

Is the manga Kingdom based on historical events and/or entities?

and if so, how historically accurate is it?

and finally, if possible, where can I read about the history of China in these times (~245 B.C.)?

Comment: For your last question (which isn't really on topic for this site), you might like to consult [this list of books](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/wiki/books/eastasia#wiki_china).

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't on topic. Mind to elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, I mean, it has nothing to do with anime/manga/etc. It's a perfectly legitimate reference request about Chinese history, but that's not really what this site is about.

Comment: Oh I understand. I realized just now that you were only refering to the last question and not the other two. Thanks for the link anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, most and maybe even all the events in Kingdom are based on historical events during the Warring States Period of ancient China (475-221 BCE). As for accurateness, of course there are some exaggerations and more spectacularity due to it being a manga/anime. But it tends to be pretty close to the historical facts we know of that time.

One of the most accurate fact list I could find can be seen on [this forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20170720120838/http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/477476-The-Ultimate-Facts-Thread-on-Kingdom-Characters).

> we are making a thread on historical facts about characters and events in Kingdom. We will be comparing characters and events in the Kingdom manga with what was recorded in the history books(as much as we know). This thread will contain mainly information on characters, both real and fictitious, in Kingdom while we will (hopefully) make another thread on events. This will hopefully answer questions that you guys might have, bust some myths, and increase your overall interest in this manga. Since we are merely history enthusiasts and not a history professor or anything, do feel free to contribute and/or point out any mistakes here. I will be using the character's pinyin names as I am more familiar with them but their Japanese names will be there under the character's "Name" section for easy reference.

As for your last question, some basic information and history can be read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period) and there are also plenty of books out there as mentioned in the comments.

Funny side note: this manga will go down in history itself as well, as it is a world record holder recognized by the Guinness Book of World Records for [manga written by most people](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-12-21/kingdom-earns-guinness-record-for-manga-written-by-most-people).

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you for all this information. I will certainly check those forums!

Comment: The link to the forum (http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/477476-The-Ultimate-Facts-Thread-on-Kingdom-Characters) is no longer working. Can you please update it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VXD Thanks for the heads up, it has been updated