# Are there any other Guinness world record holders?

Tags: one-piece, anime-history

Recently I stumbled upon a [post](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2015/6/japanese-manga-%E2%80%9Cone-piece%E2%80%9D-is-most-printed-comic-series-by-one-author-ever-385868) mentioning that One Piece managed to get a place in the [Guinness World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com) for most printed comic series by one author ever.

Are there any other manga / anime that managed to place themselves in the Guinness World Records? Or is Eiichiro Oda, with One Piece, the only one so far?

Comment: I totally forgot I also mentioned a record in [a previous answer of mine](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/8184/1458). [Kingdom, written by most people](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-12-21/kingdom-earns-guinness-record-for-manga-written-by-most-people)

Comment: And [Another one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/41775/1458) mentioned by zasha faith

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, One Piece is not the only record holder: as shown in [this article](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-09-11/kochikame-earns-guinness-world-record-for-most-volumes-published-for-single-manga-series/.106306), "Kochikame Earns Guinness World Record For Most Volumes Published For Single Manga Series" with 200 volumes.

Answer (score 3):

The ones I could find are:

[Most comics published by one author: Shotaro Ishinomori (Japan) known as "The King of Manga"](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.de/world-records/most-comics-published-by-one-author)

[Most strips published for the same yonkoma manga series](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.de/world-records/425073-most-strips-published-for-the-same-yonkoma-manga-series)

Now these are just records that I could find in a short span of time. I am sure theres a section for different manga and comics related records.

Answer (score 3):

There is another I'm aware of, although probably not what you were after: Kochikame for the most volumes published for a single manga series.

In a different category (interesting nonetheless), Yu-gi-oh is the highest selling trading card, and 1995 third volume of Weekly Shonen Jump magazine is the highest selling comic magazine. Weird, but fun facts.