# Which series features the most re-occuring named characters?

Tags: tropes

Recently I had a discussion with friends about how hard they find it to follow anime/manga series due to the sheer amount characters that get featured in a series.

They claimed [detective-conan](/questions/tagged/detective-conan) featured more than 3000 characters (roughly 5 per episode), which I debunked as most of those characters are never mentioned again.

This statement was followed by [bleach](/questions/tagged/bleach) having around 250 characters, where it was even important to remember the weapons names, as it might be important.

And Legend of Galactic Heroes which had 660 named characters, of which many where regularly re-occurring or even considered main characters.

With that my curiosity followed, which series features the most re-occurring named characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most I could find was [Anpanman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anpanman#Characters) which is a Guinness World Record Holder for a having cast consisting of 1768 characters introduced over the first 980 episodes of the TV series and the first 20 films. That doesn't include the entire cast, apparently the producer nominated even more characters but they weren't accepted.

[Guinness World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-characters-in-an-animation-series) entry.